# Transfer Data from One table to Another Table based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table name SOURCETABLE with fields RollID, SMSID, FName, Lname.
The Destination table is DestTable with field ID, FirstName , LastName.
My task is to creat DestTable from the data of SOURCETABLE with following condition:

```
If RollID = NULL
   ID = SMSID
else
   ID = RollID
end if
```

Fname will go to Firstname and Lname will go to LastName

What statement I should write?

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
INSERT INTO DestTable (ID, FirstName, LastName)
   SELECT COALESCE(RollId,SMSID), FName, LName
   FROM SourceTable
```

You can read about what COALESCE does here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: @Abe Miessler, i have a small doubt in your code, what is meant by COALESCE? i dint have got with this up to now.

Comment: `COALESCE` takes the first non-null value in the comma seperated list  you give it.  So in the example above, if `RollId` is null it will use `SMSID`

Comment: Ok, thank you @Abe Miessler for your reply. I got a new functionality to day.

Comment: @Kalyan - it's like null checking function in sql. see below link for it's definition and usage http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: @Abe Miessler: I have also write answer but your answer really good, today i got a new function.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you Kalyan.  If you think my answer solved your original question feel free to click the check mark in the top left corner of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    INSERT INTO  DestTable (Id, FirstName, LastName)
    SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(RollId,'')='' THEN SMSId ELSE RollId END, 
    FName, LName FROM SOURCETABLE
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. However if the number of fields in 1st and 2nd table then is it required to write all the fields or we can use *. For example - INSERT INTO dbo.sms (*) SELECT CASE when ISNULL(barcode1, '')='' then barcode2 else barcode1 end, * FROM sms_tmp

Comment: This is more complex than it needs to be.